# AngularJS promises with firebase (angularFire)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise, angularfire

I am trying to achieve fetching data in service and then update the view for all day long :( and i come with this but i think it's a overkill **could someone please SHOW ME THE GOOD WAY how to deal with it?**

**+ THIS DOES NOT UPDATE THE VIEW WHEN NEW SUBCATEGORY IS CREATED... AND I NEED THAT**

Structure:

```
 categories
     -JF1RmYehtF3IoGN9xHG
          name: "something" 
           ownerId: "something"
           subcategories
                  -JFBznMYEVp1ZkudEbrl: true
                  -JFDmmf6vVo8w8TpF0ny: true
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.findSubCategories = function() {
      Categories.findSubCategories($routeParams.categoryId).then(function (returnedData) {
        $scope.subCategories = returnedData;
      });
    }
```

Service:

```
      findSubCategories: function(categoryId) {
        var returnedSubcategories = [];

        var defer = $q.defer();

        var subCategoriesIdsList = FireRef.categories().child('/'+categoryId).child('subcategories');

        subCategoriesIdsList.on("child_added", function(snap) {
          FireRef.subcategories().child("/"+snap.name()).on("value", function(snap) {
            returnedSubcategories.push(snap.val());
            defer.resolve(returnedSubcategories);
            console.log("each");
          });
        });

        return defer.promise;
      },
```

Thank you a lot if someone could help!

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17458617/777436

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - are you trying to keep the subcategories for a particular category up to date in your view?

Comment: yes and what is more important i am curious about dealing with unknown number of asynchronuous callbacks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633540/loop-denormalized-data/21737084#21737084